# Does IDispatch::Invoke(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET) increment the reference count on the IDispatch interface returned?

Tags: c++, com, vb6, atl

I'm currently working on an COM server (using ATL) to be used by a closed source VB
application. So far everything is working but I want to ensure that no leaks are
there... so my question is:

Do I have to call AddRef and/or Release on an IDispatch pointer obtained via:

```
VARIANT pVar;
IDispatch->Invoke(dwDispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,
                  &dispparamsNoArgs, &pVar, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `pVar` holds an interface pointer (`IUnknown*` or `IDispatch*`), you receive it `AddRef`'fed already. You are responsible to do a matching release when you are done, which you typically do indirectly just cleaning up the variant: via [`VariantClear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> The function clears a VARIANTARG by setting the vt field to VT_EMPTY. The current contents of the VARIANTARG are released first. [...] If the vtfield is VT_DISPATCH, the object is released. [...]

By the way, there is no need to use Invoke to read property in ATL. You have nice helpers readily available:

```
CComPtr<IDispatch> pDispatch;
CComVariant vFoo;
HRESULT nFooResult = pDispatch.GetPropertyByName(L"Foo", &vFoo);
CComVariant vBar;
HRESULT nBarResult = pDispatch.GetProperty(DISPID_BAR, &vBar);
```

Wrapper classes take care of reference management.

Comment: Hi Roman! Thanks for your answer. I know about the wrappers which would work in the stripped down example I provided above. Unfortunately I cannot use them as the "real code" needs to provide additional parameters via DISPPARAMS and I haven't found a wrapper which I can use here.

Answer (score 1):

AddRef() was already called on the IDispatch pointer.  Most typically in code you cannot see, like the server's QueryInterface() method.  Pretty well hidden in ATL btw.  So the interface pointer cannot become invalid during the call, it will have a reference count of at least 1.  No additional AddRef/Release is necessary to keep it alive during the Invoke() call.  Just make sure you call Release() when you're done with it.

Fwiw, you normally leave this up to ATL's CComPtr or CComQIPtr smart pointer classes, they generate the AddRef/Release calls automatically.

If you are chasing memory leaks then you'd be looking for missing Release() calls.

Comment: Dear Hans! Thanks alot. The IDispatch* was handed over from the client so I'm not sure if it's already AddRef'fed in my use case?!